# When opening the application takes a long time to load in react native Android apk in device

Tags: load, screen, native, react-native

When open Android app takes a long time to load. It takes approximately 5 seconds. And white screen before it is displayed. please guide me .

Comment: I am guessing we are talking about the DEV mode when there's a React Packager running in the background. The first time you open the app, it takes some time to analyse and build the app you are having. If it happens in production, maybe there's any other request you are having in the app that slows it down? Any extra updates would be welcome to better answer your question.

Comment: it happens when release apk and install in device .  Mike Grabowski

Comment: @user4967246 How did you resolve this?